# Includes association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I load this from fewer queries?

Current code;
Controller;

```
@players = @season.players.includes(:stats)
```

Views;

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
    <%= player.stats.where(season: @season).each do |stat| %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Queries;

```
 Season Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "seasons".* FROM "seasons" WHERE "seasons"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Player Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "players".* FROM "players" INNER JOIN "player_seasons" ON "players"."id" = "player_seasons"."player_id" WHERE "player_seasons"."season_id" = ?  [["season_id", 1]]
  Stat Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "stats".* FROM "stats" WHERE "stats"."player_id" IN (1, 2)
  Stat Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "stats".* FROM "stats" WHERE "stats"."player_id" = ? AND "stats"."season_id" = 1  [["player_id", 1]]
  Stat Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "stats".* FROM "stats" WHERE "stats"."player_id" = ? AND "stats"."season_id" = 1  [["player_id", 2]]
  Rendered seasons/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.4ms)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the queries that are currently being used? That will give us a baseline for reducing the number of queries.

Comment: It would be better to add to the question for future users who come along. It might get deleted from imgur. It is also impossible to copy and paste if we need to.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I've updated question.

Comment: Are you intending to display any data on the player? I noticed that you are first fetching the player and then getting the players stats. If all you need are the player's stats, you could just iterate over those.

Comment: I do plan to include data on the player and stats. I would iterate other the player stats like I am currently doing but that way, every player would have a new query causing a n+1 problems. I think loading the season id and player id in the initial controller query would fix that? But not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `preload` or `eager_load` instead of `includes`?

Lots of good info about various joins and such can be found here: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Comment: I've got it working temporally with;   @players = @season.players.includes(:stats).where(stats: {season: @season})

Comment: DAn, would be nice to actually post a solution relating to the OP's question.